# Is it correct? "Should I not hear from you by [date], I shall assume your kind confirmation of it."

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is it correct to write in this way?

"Should I not hear from you by [date], I shall assume your kind confirmation of it."

Most grateful for your advice!!! T_T

Comment: There's nothing ungrammatical about it.  Know that it sounds distinctly Indian.  If you're writing to someone in India, it's perfect.  If the recipient is someone outside of India or your goal is to achieve accent neutralization, which I know is something that many Indian firms strive for in their communication, this falls short.

Comment: Why do you think it may not be correct? What exactly do you think could be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please read the FAQ. (You will earn rep for doing just that). Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am not too familiar with formal language used in the business world so I wonder if this sounds natural to write in this way.

Comment: As Billy says, your sentence, iihc, is grammatical, but I would not call it "correct" or good writing.  I would recommend something like "If I do not hear otherwise from you by [date], I will assume you agree to [whatever agreement has been under discussion]."  Or you might want to say, "Let me know whether you agree or disagree by [date].  If I do not hear from you by that time, I will assume you agree."   It might be wiser, though, to say, "If I don't hear from you by that time, I will assume you *don't* agree."

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "assume confirmation": by definition if you have not heard from the other party then they have *not* confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

In India, 'should' is used to refer to a conditional, like IF. I haven often seen official communication that reads, "Should you require more information, please contact...." Converted to negative, it becomes, "Should you not require....., the matter will be considered closed.  Thus, use of SHOULD as a conditional is correct.